# Adding game object to list while iterating over it

Tags: java, libgdx

I need to add game object to a list. In this `private ArrayList<GameObject> list;` list I save all my game data (enemies, blocks, bricks and so on...). Here how I do that

```
for(GameObject t : list){
    if(Enemy.count < 20){
        list.add(new Enemy(100, 100, true));
    }
}
```

And I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: you cant modify your array whhile you are itterating through it, one of the solution is each time when you are looping through it, is create copy. show more code then we can work out proper solution

Comment: But creating a copy sounds like waste of resources

Comment: Are you actually doing anything while iterating, or are there some lines missing from the code you have given?

Comment: First, you can create copy only for loop purpose, dont forget your copy won't holds copy of objects but only reference to them. and second thing is if you show more code, we can find you better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution would be to use another list temporarily:

```
List<GameObject> toAdd = new ArrayList<>();
for(GameObject t : list){
  if(Enemy.count < 20){
    toAdd.add(new Enemy(100, 100, true));
  }
}
list.addAll(toAdd);
```

Answer (score 2):

this code can be rewrtitten

```
   for(GameObject t : list){
        if(Enemy.count < 20){
            list.add(new Enemy(100, 100, true));
        }
    }
```

as

```
if(Enemy.count < 20){
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            list.add(new Enemy(100, 100, true));
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

you will get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException exception when you try modifying the list while iterating over it.

-Use Iterators instead of directly iterating through it, if the purpose is only to remove objects. But I see, you need to add them, hence use second method

```
Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String str = iter.next();
    if (str.equals("B")) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

---

-Use CopyOnWriteArrayList instead of simple ArrayLists and you can **use you existing code as is.**

```
List<GameObject> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<GameObject()>;
for (GameObject t : list) {
    if (Enemy.count < 20) {
        list.add(new Enemy(100, 100, true));
    }
}
```